# What does the controller vibration mean in Nintendo Land - Luigi's Ghost Mansion?

Tags: nintendo-land

For the Nintendo Wii U game "Nintendo Land," there are twelve mini-games based on well-known Nintendo IPs, one of which is based off of Luigi's Mansion: *Luigi's Ghost Mansion*.

When playing, one player uses the Wii U gamepad, and all the others use Wiimotes. When playing as the player with the Wiimote, the controller starts to vibrate randomly. What does this mean/is there a way to turn it off? It seems like it is doing so to add suspense to the "ghostly" environment of the game, but my friends and I who play the game find it slightly annoying and irritable if it has no real purpose.

Comment: Why do people downvote and never comment to say what is wrong with the question? If you have an issue with it, I can try and fix it with edits (it's kinda disrespectful to do that honestly)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller vibrates whenever the ghost is near by. That way you can tell your teammates which one of you is in danger.

Or to throw you off on the map with the suits of armor and make you think the ghost is close when he may actually not be.

As for turning it off I'm not sure if it's possible since it's a core feature unless it can be turned off from outside of the game.

Comment: Well if it actually adds functionality to the game (which from your answer it seems to), then we don't mind leaving it on. We'll have to learn how to use  it to our advantage

Comment: @ThePickleTickler Yes, it's a very important functionality of the game, it's the main help to understand the ghost's position, or at least its closeness. And the lightning, of course.